# Google maps scale custom tiles

Tags: ios, google-maps

I use google maps for my iOS app which primarily displays custom tiles.

I subclass the `GMSSyncTileLayer` and request the tile using `URLSession.shared` when I get the data back I pass it to the receiver like this:

```
let image = UIImage(data: D) ?? kGMSTileLayerNoTile
receiver.receiveTileWith(x: x, y: y, zoom: zoom, image: image)
```

This is correct according to the [Google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles) and it successfully renders my tiles:

[image]

However, the instant the user pinches to zoom in the tiles are removed from the map and the custom tiles don't show up until the next level of tiles loads.

This behavior is different from `MKMapKit` and MapBox. They both scale custom tiles before the next level loads. Google maps does this for it's own base tiles. Any idea how to get the same behavior for custom tiles on Google maps iOS SDK?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem ?

Comment: I did not. Have not worked on this problem in a while but I suspect it's not possible.